# Can I use 64bit JDK for develop, on a 32bit Windows?

Tags: java, android, windows, 64-bit

Due to some weird of my office rule, I can only run Windows7 32bit.

I know it's OK to install a 64bit JDK on 32bit Windows, but will it cause problem while my Java program/AndroidAPP runs on any other machine ?

Comment: It's actually not OK to install 64bit on 32bit Windows.

Comment: Maybe you will get help by reading this blog post of oracle https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/choosing-64-andor-32-bit-java

Comment: if we have 32 bit jdk also available then why you are trying to install 64 bit JDK on 32 bit system?

Answer (score 2):

No. Because it will not run. If it did run, then it would be fine. You can use a 32bit JDK on 32bit Windows. You can use a 32bit JDK on 64bit Windows. And you can use a 64bit JDK on 64bit Windows.